# Removing Carpet Glue

Tags: outdoor, carpet

I installed outdoor carpet on my porch.  The glue bled through in spots.  What can I use to remove the spots from the carpet?

Comment: What type of glue did you use? A solvent based or water based glue? The brand name would be helpful in directing you to the correct chemical or process.

Comment: I used Roberts Indoor/Outdoor Carpet Adhesive

Comment: I'm curious if the carpet was inexpensive enough, is it worthwhile to remove, replace, and try again with a different method? Can you share a picture of the bleed through? I'm trying to picture how much work it might be to cleanup, and even if you get the glue to release/dissolve, getting that out of carpet could be a challenge in-itself.

Answer (score 1):

Roberts 8000 concentrated stripper is suggested by mfg for glue removal. The roberts adhesive you used is a solvent free adhesive so best to use what they recommend. This a concentrated latex adhesive remover so you will want to probably apply it to a cloth and work the spots to remove the stains. Non VOC and enviromentaly according to the documentation.

Comment: Will this damage the carpet?

Comment: It is used to glue it down so I would not expect it to cause damage but test a small area to be sure.

Comment: The problem is that I used Roberts to glue it down, but the glue bled thru the carpet in spots.  That's what I need to remove.

Comment: I understand you used their adhesive. roberts 8000 is a concentrated stripper made for thier adhesives. There are many latex strippers out there but for best results I use one made by the same company or recommended by the company that makes the adhesives if I spill some or have bleed through at a seam.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a carpet installer; I use mineral spirits to clean glue.

When installing glue-down carpet, you should use a 1/16th notched trowel and spread it evenly with no glops, and right up to all edges. You also need to wait till it dries and is tacky (1/2 hour more or less) before you lay the carpet down. This avoids the issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F12k2J3ouYg

Answer (score -2):

Try acetone nail polish remover.[image]

Comment: Almost all carpet is made from plastic (i.e., recycled soda/popbottles)... Acetone will eat this plastic material and make a much bigger mess.

Comment: It comes in a plastic bottle. I use nail polish remover as a glue remover all the time, works great.

Comment: Will nail polish remover harm the carpet?

Comment: I'm near positive it will harm the carpet. No acetone does not eat all plastics, but if you are going to try to use it on the carpet, test it on a scrap.

Comment: I'm not making this up, I do this for a living.

Comment: Added a pic of acetone in a cheap dollar store plastic bag, and a cheap made in Pakistan table towel dowsed in acetone. Short of going in the shed and dumping it on a cheap piece of rental carpet, not sure what other proof you want. You can believe the innerwebs, or real life. Your choice.

Comment: @NPM, I'm not attempting to personally attack you. Nor am I calling you an inanimate object with a derogatory or superiority pretense. I am simply stating a definite fact - Acetone absolutely can and will dissolve MANY plastics (Not all), but many. More than ONE!  Check the chemical formula's and some chemistry references & you will learn this is true. As someone who has used Acetone on MANY things (including plastic) I can say as a human being with experience that Acetone can and will absolutely damage plastic, potentially hers. I stand by my recommendation against your answer knowing this.

Comment: Here ya go, a plastic item, that acetone ate like the blob :)  seriously though, acetone does damage some plastics, thus the recommendation against it's use on "unknown" plastic.  http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2006/how-to-extract-magnets-from-plastic-toys/